# Unable to set FlatList height inside a Modal

Tags: react-native

Normally the height of a FlatList is set by wrapping a  around it.
This doesn't appear to work if I put it inside a modal component of react native.

Is there any other way to set the height for a FlatList?

```
<Modal
visible={visible}
transparent={true}
animationType='slide'
>

<View style={middleInnerContainer}>
    <FlatList
    data={this.props.vegetablesBenefit}
    renderItem={modalBenefitItem}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
    scrollEnabled
    />
</View>
</Modal>
```

I've simplified this code to the basic structure I am using. 
It works perfectly fine outside of a modal.

Comment: Add some code to validate your question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? If you want a list inside a popup you can simply use the following code I wrote for creating a generic dialog popup!

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.closeDialog()}>
        <Modal
          visible={this.state.showDialog}
          transparent={true}
          onRequestClose={() => this.closeDialog()}
          animationType='slide'>
          {/* tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty */}
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.closeDialog()}>
            <View style={styles.parentContainer}>
              <View style={styles.childContainer}>
                <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
                  {/* tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty */}
                  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { }}>
                    <View>
                      <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>{this.props.headerTitle} 
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                  {this.renderListComponent()}
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </Modal>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Handles the touch outside as well. Let me know if this completes your requirement.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Ideally I need to use a FlatList inside the modal since the list has a variable number of rows depending on the trigger for the modal. I'm struggling with sizing the FlatList to the same size as the modal and also having it being scrollable.

Comment: Hi, With this you can achieve it. Did you check styling the outer views by giving the fixed height?

Comment: It does, {this.renderListComponent()} is the flatlist component.